# Copy string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I would like to convert this constructor's argument from `const char*` to `std::string`, but I don't know how to copy the *new name* to *name* properly.

```
Player::Player(const char* name) :
        level(1),life(1),strength(1),place(0){
    char* new_player_name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy(new_player_name, name);
    this->player_name = new_player_name;
}

Player::Player(string name) :
        level(1),life(1),strength(1),place(0){
    string new_player_name(' ',name.length() + 1); //#1
// I didn't know how to proceed 
}
```

The classes data-members:

```
class Player {
    char* player_name;
    int level;
    int life;
    int strength;
    int place;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider making `player_name` a `std::string`.

Then your constructor could start

```
Player::Player(const char* name) : player_name(name)
{
```

and you don't need to fiddle about with all those dynamically allocated `char` arrays.

You could change the type of `name` to a `const std::string&` too:

```
Player::Player(const std::string& name) : player_name(name)
{
```

Comment: Player::Player(string name) : player_name(name) you meant like this right?

Comment: @Yasmin12: Personally I'd pass by const reference to obviate a sting copy (although a compiler might optimise it out). See the amended answer.

Comment: Not quite, you could use `const char* name` as parameter or `const string& name` as @Bathsheba said.
I recommend you to read [specs of string class here] (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)

Comment: Personally, *I* would pass by `std::string_view` to obviate the need to construct or have available a `std::string` at all. It's a shame there's no variant of `std::string_view` which has a 0-terminator like `std::string` does though.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Well I say, that's rippingly posh. (You might want to answer to explain why.)